# Tomcat6 failed to restart

Tags: tomcat6

I have tomcat6 installed with Geoserver 7 on it.

After trying to restart error appears in `catalina.out`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.Currency                  
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:559)            
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:94)                 
        at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:157)           
        at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:767)                           
        at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(NumberFormat.java:439)                    
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:581)                    
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:570)                        
        at java.text.DateFormat.get(DateFormat.java:724)                                       
        at java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.java:499)                           
        at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1407)                         
        at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:475)                        
        at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:367)                              
        at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:70)                   
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:198)                           
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:573)                                       
        at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:598)                                     
        at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:798)                                      
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:167)                     
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:135)                   
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:100)          
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:207)                      
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:391)
```

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sad, but openjdk-6-jre-headless become incompatible with new tzdata-java.

So, I need to update to version 7

Comment: I ran into this same exception randomly on a server (probably think due to a hardware problem). Reinstalling openjdk-6-jre-headless fixed it. So thanks for that!